# Check if a value is null?

Tags: javascript, html, text, if-statement, null

In javascript, I want to have an if else statement that will change an elements value(a text field in an html form) to zero if nothing is typed in. I had the following:

```
if(document.getElementById('dollarinput').value == null){
    var dollars = 0;
}
else{
    var dollars = parseInt(document.getElementById('dollarinput').value);
}
```

Something isn't working correctly in the if condition, but I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Care to tell is what exactly doesn't work correctly?

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa. The problem is `'' == null // false` and value can never be `null`.... though you're right in your comment!

Comment: @gdoron I know. I just would like to educate OP how to ask a question rather than giving a vague description. :-)

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa. I got the feeling we had that exact conversion couple weeks ago...

Comment: @gdoron wouldn't surprise me ;)

Comment: Why has this been voted down? And did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the variable declaration above the `if` and check for empty quotes, like so:

```
var dollars;
if(document.getElementById('dollarinput').value == ''){
    dollars = 0;
}
else{
    dollars = parseInt(document.getElementById('dollarinput').value);
}
```

Comment: moving the variable deceleration outside the if isn't necessary in javascript! if isn't a new scope!

Comment: True, but the fact that he was adding two variables with the same name which would both assume the same scope would cause him problems :)

Comment: Well it wouldn't know which one it was setting?

Comment: Please read about hoisting. and no, there can't be two variable in the same scope with the same name!

Comment: Actually you're right, I just checked via fiddle :). My answer still solves the fact that he's not checking for an empty string though :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's an empty string instead:

```
if(document.getElementById('dollarinput').value == ''){
    var dollars = 0;
} else{
    var dollars = parseInt(document.getElementById('dollarinput').value, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Value of an input can never be `null` ! if there is no value, it will be an empty string.
- `alert('' == null);​​ // false`

**Fixed code:**

```
if(document.getElementById('dollarinput').value){
    var dollars = 0;
}
else{
    var dollars = parseInt(document.getElementById('dollarinput').value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dollars = 0;
var dollarinput = document.getElementById('dollarinput');
if( ! dollarinput.length )
{
    dollars = parseInt(dollarinput.value);
}
```